# apache camel route to split sql results

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-camel

I am trying to do is select all rows from DB, and for each row update some column for that row. Below is my camel route.

```
from("direct:insert").
from("sql:select * from my_table").
split(body()).
log("${body[id]}").
end();
```

I use the below code to start this route...

```
context.createProducerTemplate().sendBody("direct:insert", null);
```

Problem is it happens multiple times (i.e. all the id's from my_table are printed around 18 times!!). How do i make it happen just once?

Comment: I don't understand the question: First you want to split the results for updating rows, but you don't want to log each id of the row(this should be logged only once)? Could you pls clarify your question?

Comment: Change the from("sql:select * from my_table") --> to("sql:select * from my_table") that fixed it for me

Comment: Hi Ashok, that worked for me. Do you want to post an answer so i can mark your answer as correct? If not, then i'll just add one on my own..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code worked fine for me..

```
from("direct:insert").
to("sql:select * from my_table").
split(body()).
log("${body[id]}").
end();
```